Windows Batch File to check version of program in registry, skip or update based on version
I'm trying to work up a script to deploy with a GPO that will do the following:

Check the pertinent PCs for what version of our VPN software is installed via registry query
If the VPN software is not current, uninstall the old version and install the current version
If the VPN software is current, do nothing
End

Where it seems to go wrong is the reg query. Regardless of whether the VPN software is outdated or current, the script performs the uninstall and reinstall.
This is what I have been using.
@echo off

:10
REM Check installed version of VPN client, end if current - v6.3.1-376 - update if not current
for /f "skip=2 tokens=2" %%i in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\VPNClient" /v "Version"') do set "keyValue=%%i"
if not "keyValue%" == "6.3.1-376" goto 20 else goto 999

:20
REM Uninstall old version of VPN client
start /wait MsiExec.exe /X{62BC3D77-3D5D-4821-B162-5BF52C6B11AF} /quiet /norestart
goto :30

:30
REM Install current version of VPN client - v6.3.1-376
pushd "\\ourdomain.com\Directory_Containing_The_Installer"
start /wait msiexec /i vpnclientinstaller.msi /quiet /norestart
popd
goto 999

:999
end

This command:
reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\VPNClient" /v "Version"

outputs this at a cmd prompt.
Version    REG_SZ    6.3.1-376

What am I missing here?
Revised code from comment:
@echo off

:10 
REM Check installed version of GlobalProtect client, end if current - v6.3.1-376 - update if not current 
for /f "skip=3 tokens=3" %%i in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\VPNClient" /v "Version"') do set "keyValue=%%i" 
if not "%keyValue%" == "6.3.1-376" (goto 20) else goto 999

:20
REM Uninstall old version of VPN client
start /wait MsiExec.exe /X{62BC3D77-3D5D-4821-B162-5BF52C6B11AF} /quiet /norestart
goto :30

:30
REM Install current version of VPN client - v6.3.1-376
pushd "\\ourdomain.com\Directory_Containing_The_Installer"
start /wait msiexec /i vpnclientinstaller.msi /quiet /norestart
popd
goto 999

:999
end


The first token is Version, the second %%i, is REG_SZ. If you want the third change tokens to 2,* and use %%j for 6.3.1-376; or else change tokens to 3 to propagate %%i with 6.3.1-376.

I have updated the first section like this:
:10
REM Check installed version of GlobalProtect client, end if current - v6.3.1-376 - update if not current
for /f "skip=3 tokens=3" %%i in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\VPNClient" /v "Version"') do set "keyValue=%%i"
if not "%keyValue%" == "6.3.1-376" (goto 20) else goto 999
Still seems to be not recognizing that the version is current and it's running the install regardless.

There was no need to change skip=2 to skip=3. The result you are trying to parse is from the third line of output. If you skip the third line, there is nothing to retrieve tokens from. Please change it back to skip=2, or remove it completely.


I've included the revised code from the comment into the original batch. OP:please check that the revised code I have posted is the same as your code.

Note especially that the modification from :999 end to :999 end is correct.
@echo off

SETLOCAL

:10 
REM Check installed version of GlobalProtect client, end if current - v6.3.1-376 - update if not current
set "keyValue=" 
for /f "tokens=3" %%i in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\VPNClient" /v "Version" 2^>nul') do set "keyValue=%%i" 
if "%keyValue%" == "6.3.1-376" (goto 999) else goto 20

:20
REM Uninstall old version of VPN client
if not defined keyvalue goto 30

start /wait MsiExec.exe /X{62BC3D77-3D5D-4821-B162-5BF52C6B11AF} /quiet /norestart
goto :30

:30
REM Install current version of VPN client - v6.3.1-376
pushd "\\ourdomain.com\Directory_Containing_The_Installer"
start /wait msiexec /i vpnclientinstaller.msi /quiet /norestart
popd
goto 999

:999
end

Revisions:

Include a setlocal.
Always use a setlocal flavour to avoid environment clutter. Normally, a setlocal line should follow @echo off. If you omit this line, variables set by running one batch file will remain set when the next is run in the same cmd instance, potentially yielding different results when the same script is run repeatedly.

Included a set "keyValue=" to force keyValue to be undefined before the for is executed

Omitted the skip=3.
On my test, the response from reg query was only 2 lines, so the set would not be executed. Hence keyvalue would "have a value" of nothing. Thus it would not match 6.3.1-376, goto 20 and uninstall/reinstall. keyvalue would be assigned the value of the 3rd token in each non-empty reg query line in turn, and would retain the value from the last-encountered 3rd token when the for finishes.

Included 2^>nul in the reg query command.
This disposes of error messages should the key not be found. The ^ tells cmd that the > is part of the reg command, not the for.

Revised the awkward double-negative condition.
In some cultures, doubling a negative intensifies the negative rather than inverts it. Regardless, the code is simplified for everyone - AND the else condition is superfluous since the next "command" executed is ":20"

included if not defined keyvalue goto 30 to skip the uninstall step should keyvalue be undefined which implies that the software is not installed.


[7.] The `goto :30' is superfluous as the next "command" is ":30". The colon is superfluous in this statement in any case.
[8.] Originally the code read :999 end. The text following the labelSpace would be ignored and there is no such command as end (already noted)

This appears to have done it! I can see that the VPN client is updating on the laptops, except for a stubborn few. Thanks so much to everyone for the help!
